# Changing the text of a label on button press with dynamic integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm following a tutorial to create a simple game where you tap a button and the the game counts how many times you have pressed the button as you go along. The score is displayed on screen in the form of a label.

I can make it so that when you press the button the label text changes to say 'Pressed!'. But then i can not get the label to change when i try to add the changing score with a format specifier.

```js
-(IBAction)buttonPressed{
  count ++;
  //scoreLabel.text =@"pressed";
  scoreLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i", count];
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You may not have your label set up for multiple lines of text. Try getting rid of the "\n" in your format string. Other than that, you need to tell us what happens. Have you put a breakpoint to make sure your button IBAction is being called? Have you checked to make sure "scoreLable" (sic) is not nil? The devil is in the details.

Comment: Learning to debug your programs is one of the most important skills in development. It's just about impossible to tell why a program isn't working by looking at it. You need to set breakpoints, examine variables, add NSLog statements, etc. Learn those skills early and well.

Comment: This was exactly it! NSLog was showing the count go up but I couldn't work out why the label wasn't changing. And it ended up being something as simple as setting the label to 2 lines. I'm very embarrassed. Thank you.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer. You should accept it so others can tell the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have your label set up for multiple lines of text. Try getting rid of the "\n" in your format string. Other than that, you need to tell us what happens. Have you put a breakpoint to make sure your button IBAction is being called? Have you checked to make sure "scoreLable" (sic) is not nil? The devil is in the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed : (id) sender{

    UIButton * btnPressed = (UIButton *)sender;

    int buttonValue = [[btnPressed titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] intValue];

    NSLog(@"Button value = %d", buttonValue);

    //scoreLabel.text =@"pressed";
    scoreLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i", count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First You Can Set  `static int  count = 0;`